# Media Query para diferentes níveis de zoom?

Tags: html, css, query

Gostaria de utilizar valores '**em**' no Media Query, só que para diferentes tipos de zoom no navegador como `100%` `125%` `175%` e assim vai indo.

Quais valores eu deveria utilizar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que acontece é que quando vc da o Zoom com o Browser na verdade vc está diminuindo a largura da tela na verdade

Ex: Se a sua tela tem 1000px de largura e vc aumenta o zoom para 150% na realidade é como se a sua tela estivesse com 500px de largura. Aqui tem uma calculadora que vai te dar os números para a sua tela: http://mqtest.io/

Então vc pode usar os @medias para determinar algumas larguras aproximadas em PX para o níveis de Zoom. **Lembrando sempre que quanto maior o Zoom menor a largura da tela!**

- Aqui tem um artigo sobre como tratar e proceder com o `font-size` Desktop x Mobile: https://varvy.com/mobile/legible-font-size.html (no Google vc encontra mais)

Agora pensando em fonte responsiva vc pode fazer alguns teste com o `font-size` em **VW**. Veja nesse exemplo. Quanto mais vc da Zoom com o Browser todas as fontes aumentam, menos as que estão com o tamanho em **VW** (vermelho). **OBS:** Essa opção tem que ser analisada com cuidado principalmente pensando no seu público alvo e tipo de dispositivo que usam!

```css
.vw {
    font-size: 4vw;
}
.rem {
    font-size: 2rem;
}
.pre {
    font-size: 200%;
}
.em {
    font-size: 2em;
}

.rem1 {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.vw1 {
    font-size: 2vw;
}
.pre1 {
    font-size: 100%;
}
.em1 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

.vw, .vw1 {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="rem">H1 com 2rem (32px)</h1>
<h1 class="vw">H1 com 4vw</h1>
<h1 class="per">H1 com 200%</h1>
<h1 class="em">H1 com 2em</h1>
<p class="rem1"> < P > com 1rem (16px)</p>
<p class="vw1"> < P > com 2vw</p>
<p class="per1"> < P > com 100%</p>
<p class="em1"> < P > com 1em</p>
```