# Como fazer para que o texto se adapte ao tamanho da div?

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma `div` que tem as dimensões `widht` e `height` em 100% do tamanho da tela. Dentro dela, tenho um texto encapsulado em `p`.

Como faço pra definir o `font-size` de modo que ele fique com a mesma proporção em telas de tamanho diferentes ou caso o usuário redimensione a guia?

Comment: Cara eu dei uma pesquisada e não encontrei nada tão dinâmico quando vc precisa... Mas as vezes perguntando no Stack gringo alguém tem uma resposta pra te dar...

Answer (score 3):

***O que vou comentar aqui é apenas a ponta do `iceberg`***

Para entender melhor aconselho a leitura desses dois artigos! https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/ e https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/05/fluid-typography/

Nesses artigos vc vai ver que existe uma abordagem que chega nesse resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E daria esse resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O modelo base do CSS para uma tipografia fluida segundo o artigo da Smashing Magazine do [Michael Riethmuller](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/author/michaelriethmuller/) seria assim:

```
/* Older browsers */
html { font-size: 16px; }

/* Modern browsers only need this one */

@media screen and (min-width: 25em){
  html { font-size: calc( 16px + (24 - 16) * (100vw - 400px) / (800 - 400) ); }
}

/* Safari <8 and IE <11 */
@media screen and (min-width: 25em){
  html { font-size: calc( 16px + (24 - 16) * (100vw - 400px) / (800 - 400) ); }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 50em){

html { font-size: calc( 16px + (24 - 16) * (100vw - 400px) / (800 - 400) ); }
}
```

---

Colocando o texto simplesmente em `vw`, *viewport width* Vc teria esse resultado, e precisaria de um tratamento com `@media` para não deixar o texto muito pequeno quando a tela for muito estreita...

Repare que assim a linha nunca quebra, porem o tamanho vai ficando muito pequeno, pois é em proporção a largura do *viewport*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo:

```css
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
div {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
p {
 font-size: 1vw;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
 <div>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corporis, facilis optio cupiditate ducimus animi ea quidem odit eum error corrupti ratione impedit illo sed nesciunt culpa velit repellendus eius, praesentium est quasi! Nobis ab magnam, laudantium obcaecati voluptatibus esse. Impedit repudiandae temporibus molestias cum dolorum ipsum qui, voluptates accusantium expedita esse cumque fuga earum cupiditate excepturi in eos ad, nihil commodi quae aspernatur itaque! Fuga distinctio autem nulla, accusamus minus hic obcaecati tempora accusantium consectetur! Vitae, in distinctio ipsum sint laudantium beatae natus, inventore, nam aspernatur explicabo quo accusantium quia quam quibusdam. Cumque voluptate excepturi culpa dolor pariatur nostrum, possimus impedit eum modi. Impedit dignissimos nesciunt quia iure beatae tempore suscipit ipsam, asperiores harum ullam facilis labore assumenda debitis quae eum ut corrupti ad, recusandae dolorum delectus, repellendus deleniti dolore? Culpa rerum vitae accusantium saepe, pariatur similique quam quia aspernatur nemo inventore atque quos, laudantium at ipsam earum. Officia ab beatae rem cumque eaque ea debitis, veniam corporis voluptatum doloremque. Est et numquam tenetur beatae facere a cumque, necessitatibus deserunt veritatis at adipisci in voluptatem eaque sunt aliquam iure maxime doloremque quam tempora. Sapiente quibusdam, blanditiis accusamus sequi quam autem consequuntur earum praesentium eveniet. Eum corporis perspiciatis veniam at excepturi.
  </p>
 </div>
```

---

Repare também que como a media `VW` é relativa a largura do *viewport* mesmo vc dando **Zoom** no Browser o tamanho do texto que está em `VW` continua com o mesmo "tamanho" Nessa resposta tem outros detalhes sobre esse comportamento de **Zoom**: [Media Query para diferentes níveis de zoom?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/288053/media-query-para-diferentes-n%C3%ADveis-de-zoom/288067#288067)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A métrica `vw` me atenderia. Mas eu preciso também ajustar em relação ao `vh`. Preciso que o texto preencha toda a tela, mesmo que cause distorção.

Comment: Acho que entendi... nesse caso acho que só com Canvas... SVG pode ser uma opção pra vc? Se sim acho que SVG eu consigo fazer um exemplo pra ti....

Comment: Acho que svg não rola pois o conteúdo do texto é dinâmico.

Comment: Vc pode ter uma tag `<div> <svg><text>seu texto</text></text> </div>` direto no corpo do html... não sei se te ajuda

Comment: Pode fazer um exemplo? Grato.

Comment: @RafaelSilva me da um tempinho e já te respondo, se der certo vou fazer outra resposta para não embolar as coisas, pois uma não vai ter nada a ver com a outra!

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, sugiro a leitura sobre as unidade de medida em css do W3: [CSS: em, px, ct, cm, etc](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.pt_BR.html)

Você pode usar uma unidade de medida que seja proporcional ao tamanho. Para isso você pode usar a unidade `vw` ou *viewport width*, que é relativa ao que pode ser visto de acordo com o tamanho (width), ou seja, irá variar de acordo como o tamanho.

Exemplo: `font-size: 3vw`

Para documentar, o `1vw` é equivalente a 1/100 (um centésimo) do tamanho do *viewport* da tela.

Outra forma é usando *media queries* (mais informação aqui no Mozilla: [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries)).

Você pode usar *media query* para definir um tamanho específico de acordo com a resolução, isso é uma boa opção também. Basicamente você define um tamanho "padrão" e ajusta o tamanho de acordo com a resolução, por exemplo usando a unidade de medida `em`.

Exemplo:

```
body {
  font-size: 14px;
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  body { font-size: 1.2em; }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  body { font-size: 1.1; }
}
@media (max-width: 468px) {
  body { font-size: 1em; }
}
```